# Show alert on clicking image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it so that an alert pops up when you click the image but for some reason it doesn't work and tells me I need to put a ")" even though one is already there. Someone pls help.

```
 <img src="descarga (3).png" height="20">
        <button 
        onclick=(alert('yay you clicked'))
        >
            click me!! </button>
```

Comment: You need ```onclick="alert('yay you clicked')"```. Nevertheless the onclick should be on the image if you want to trigger it on image click vs on button click.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the listener to the image itself and not to the button.

```js
const img = document.querySelector('#some_img');
img.addEventListener('click', () => alert('Hello World!'));
```

```html
<img id='some_img' src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.freeimages.com%2Fimages%2Flarge-previews%2F43d%2Fdummy-1536702.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=e4d5a59257d3771e098561d3e2d0fb317319369a3546b1d8d5f1576cbc5d61eb&ipo=images" height="100"/>
```

Comment: @OP Note that this answer is also using unobtrusive event handlers bound in JS, not in HTML, which is by far he better practice.

Comment: thanks! thats just the answer i needed!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display alert on image you need to add onclick in image and also wrap alert in ""

```html
<img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3048/3048127.png" height="40" onclick="alert('yay you clicked')" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `"` around the js function in the declaration of `onclick`.

Something like :

```html
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Please see : [event onclick doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax Error - use "" instead ()

```
<button onclick="alert('yay you clicked')">click me!!</button>
```